# how to get the value of a column dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd

aa = pd.DataFrame({"a": [{'item': '',
 'item2': {'value1': {'ol': 'true'},
  'value2': 'I want to take this value',
  'type': 'text'}}]})\
```

I wish to get the 'value2' values which is "I want to take this value".
I remember there is a method which do something like this.

aa.item2.value2 and then it will print the value for 'value2'.

Is there anyone use this method before?

Comment: if you want access the values of dictionary why storing it as a dataframe? directly you can access values from dictionary

Comment: `print(aa['a'][0]['item2']['value2'])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may looking for `str`

```
>>> aa.a.str["item2"].str["value2"]
0    I want to take this value
Name: a, dtype: object
```